# Execute a PM2 Command With Node.js

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'd like to execute `pm2 restart IDOFMYAPP` using NodeJS... Is that possible?

Something like that :

```js
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("pm2 restart IDOFMYAPP", puts);
```

Actually, I want to create a button to execute this code above but my button is in a view in my app that I want to restart...

**EDIT #1**

```js
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Function.app.listen (C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\node_modules\microscope-web\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:546:24)
    at _.extend.run (C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\node_modules\microscope-web\libs\Application.js:109:27)
    at Application.extend.initialize (C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\Application.js:23:10)
    at Application (C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\node_modules\microscope-web\libs\Application.js:31:19)
    at new child (C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\node_modules\microscope-web\libs\utils.js:17:27)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\bin\www:11:16

npm ERR! microscope_application@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the microscope_application@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the microscope_application package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls microscope_application
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm
```

**EDIT #2**

```js
var shell = require('shelljs');

shell.exec('pm2 restart IDOFMYAPP', function(code, output) {
  console.log('Exit code:', code);
  console.log('Program output:', output);
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like so:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');

shell.exec('pm2 restart IDOFMYAPP', function(code, output) {
  console.log('Exit code:', code);
  console.log('Program output:', output);
});
```

Comment: EADDRINUSE  means that you have another service running on the same port.

Comment: Ok, so it works now, but how to redirect to '/' after success exec??

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? It sounds like creating another question might be more appropriate.

Comment: See edit#2 above... Because your code works but my web page seems to not appreciate the `pm2 restart IDOFMYAPP`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67606/discussion-between-rahat-mahbub-and-tonymx227).